# Improve Kusto Query - mailbox audit log search

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to identify shared mailboxes that aren't in use. Checked "Search-MailboxAuditLog" already and some mailboxes do not return any results even tho auditing enabled, but can see activity in Azure sentinel.

1. Is there a way to improve below Kusto code? (During testing tried mailboxes with activities but sometimes do not get any results from the query)
2. With Kusto, Is there a way to loop through "mbs" like powershell "foreach ( $item in $mbs)"?

Thanks,

```
let mbs = datatable (name: string)
[
"xxx1@something.com",
"xxx2@something.com",
"xxx3@something.com",
];
OfficeActivity
| where OfficeWorkload == "Exchange" and TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
| where MailboxOwnerUPN in~ (mbs)
| distinct MailboxOwnerUPN
```

Update : Need help with the query

- Input would be list of shared mailbox UPNs
- Output would be list of shared mailboxes with any activity, example MBs with any action in “Operation" filed

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying that the source data is incorrect, or the source data is correct and you need help in writing a KQL query. If it's the former, then the question isn't related to KQL. If it's the latter, then please provide sample input and expected output, and we'll help with writing the KQL query. Once you update the question, please ping by adding a comment here.

Comment: Thanks, help with the query ..
Input is list of shared mailbox UPNs
Output is list of shared mailboxes with any activity, example MBs with any action in “Operation" filed

Comment: As I requested in the previous comment, please update the question with sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

"in" doesn't work on datatables (tabular inputs) like that; it is not a "filter", it is an "operator". The "where" is effectively the "foreach" you are referring to.

Given the sample input, the query could probably be written as:

```
OfficeActivity //tabular input with many records
| TimeGenerated > ago(30d) //Filter records to window of interest first
| where OfficeWorkload == "Exchange" //foreach row
| where MailboxOwnerUPN in~ ( //foreach row
    "xxx1@something.com","xxx2@something.com","xxx3@something.com"
)
| distinct MailboxOwnerUPN
```

You can see it in the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/inoperator#arguments where "col" is the "column to filter"

Comment: Also, if the mailboxes need to be defined as a variable, you can use, 
`let mbs = dynamic(["xxx1@something.com","xxx2@something.com","xxx3@something.com"]);` and then use the `in` operator.